# Performance issue with update in postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, typeorm

I've got a pretty simple `update` statement in my application in one of the APIs.

```
UPDATE "table" SET "column" = "column" + 1 WHERE "id" = $1
```

The problem is when this API incurs a sudden load it starts to fail. There is no increase in DB CPU only the number of active sessions shoot up. When checking the RDS performance insights this is what I see. [image]

The number of updates to this table doesn't shoot up more than 300. I don't think postgres should be behaving this way with such low number of updates (time spent in waits). It'll be helpful if I could have suggestions what might be going wrong here? I understand what does wait in tuple and transactionid mean but how can I reduce these waits?

Thanks

Comment: "The number of updates to this table doesn't shoot up more than 300"  The evidence you show suggests otherwise.

Comment: I think you can get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is obvious: all these sessions are waiting for a row lock. If all these sessions are running the statement you quote with the same `id` (or only a low number of different `id`s), then they are blocking each other.

Since the sessions don't seem to do any work (if I read the graph right, they are all waiting), I'd say that the problem is that your transactions are taking too long. PostgreSQL holds the row lock, like all other user-facing locks, until the transaction ends, so having that `UPDATE` in your workload effectively serializes processing.

You could improve the situation by performing the `UPDATE` at the very end of the transaction, so that the lock is not held for a long time. In addition, you should reduce your connection pool size considerably. I don't think that your database can deal with 1000 active connections.

Comment: Oops. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out @Laurenz. Moved the update at the end of the transaction. I'm gonna observe this for a few days now as this happens once or twice in a couple of weeks under heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

*Reduce* the maximum number of parallel HTTP requests your web server accepts (assuming HTTP(S)) so you don't overload the database. This will cause the API requests to your service to queue waiting for a TCP connection. This will result in improved performance rather than worse at time of peak loads.